# Unity post processing area

Tags: unity-game-engine, post-processing

I'm trying o find a way to render the post processing inside a sphere only, but outside the sphere no post processing.

**For example**, my player...has an invisible sphere around him and it moves with him...I want to make the area of the invisible sphere around him with 0 saturation (grayscale), & anything outside the sphere is normal with normal saturation.
is there any way for that?

Answer (score 0):

A more lightweight solution could be with a simple shader to place on a Sphere that follows your character.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/bfv9lv/black_and_white_shader_filter_tutorial/

In this link they do the same thing with a cube :)